# How to change the title and the body of a jQuery dialog box from $.data() sent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I am trying to use the jQuery dialog box to handle Inbound phone calls from a telephony system.

To give the user a meaningful info about the caller I will need to update the body of the dialog with something like this

```
Incomming Call From: 5421112222
Merchant ID: 123456
Account ID: 2222222
```

also would like to also update the time of the dialog with something like this.
Incomming Call From: 5421112222

Also, if I want to hide the title altogether, how can I do that?

Here is my code where I am trying to set the title value to data passed using `.data()` in the title I get `Incoming Call From: Undefined` and the body of the dialog does not change.

```
    $( "#inboundDialog" ).dialog({
        resizable: true,
        width: 400,
        modal: false,
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Incoming Call From: ' + $(this).data('phone'),
        html: 'Incoming Call From: ' + $(this).data('phone') + '<br>Merchant ID: ' + $(this).data('mid') + '<br>Account ID: ' + $(this).data('account_id'),
        stack: false,
        buttons: {
            "Answer": function(e) {
                $.ajax({    
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'inderations.php',     
                    data: {'method': 'answer', 'interactionId': $(this).data('interactionId')},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    timeout: 5000,
                    success: function(data) {           
                        console.log('answered!!!');
                        $( "#inboundDialog" ).dialog('close');
                    }
                }); 

            },
            "Send to Voice Mail": function(e) {
                $.ajax({    
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'inderations.php',     
                    data: {method: 'sendToVoiceMail', interactionId: $(this).data('interactionId') },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    timeout: 5000,
                    success: function(data) {           
                        console.log('Voice mail sent!!!');
                        $( "#inboundDialog" ).dialog('close');
                    }
                }); 
            },
            "Hold": function(e) {
                $.ajax({    
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'inderations.php',     
                    data: {method: 'holdInbound', interactionId: $(this).data('interactionId')},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    timeout: 5000,
                    success: function(data) {           
                        console.log('Place on hold!!!');
                        $( "#inboundDialog" ).dialog('close');

                    }
                }); 

            }
        }
    });
```

this is how I open the dialog when there is an inbound call

```
//incoming call 
                    if(Eic_CallDirection == 'I'){

                        //Offering/Alerting calls
                        if( Eic_State == 'A' || Eic_State == 'O' ){

                            console.log('Incoming Call From ' + Eic_RemoteAddress);

                            //display a dialog message
                            if( $("#inboundDialog").dialog( "isOpen" ) !== true){
                                $( "#inboundDialog" ).data({'interactionId': interactionId,
                                                            'phone': Eic_RemoteAddress,
                                                            'mid': mid,
                                                            'account_id': account_id
                                                            }).dialog('open');
                            }

                            return;
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work.

I decided to just remove the dialog title since it is redundant in this case.

to change the body of the dialog before open I set the `.html()` value like this

`$( "#inboundDialog" ).html('Incoming Call From ' + Eic_RemoteAddress + '<br>' + msg)`

Then to remove the title I used `.siblings('.ui-dialog-titlebar').remove()`

Here is my code put together

```
                        //display a dialog message
                        if( $("#inboundDialog").dialog( "isOpen" ) !== true){

                            $( "#inboundDialog" ).html('Incoming Call From ' + Eic_RemoteAddress + '<br>' + msg);
                            $( "#inboundDialog" ).data({'id': interactionId}).dialog('open').siblings('.ui-dialog-titlebar').remove();
                        }
```